# Coding style: function and procedures coding standard

Tags: php, coding-style, code-complete

Ch 7.6 of Code Complete 2 is confusing me, I've attached some sample code (in php) mind telling me which style is the best? or suggest something better? thanks

Style 1

```
public function register($user, $pass) {
 if($this->model->isRegistered($user)
 {
  return false;
 }
 else if($this->twitter->login($user, $pass))
 {
  return $this->model->addUser($user, $pass);
 }

 return false;
}
```

Style 2

```
public function register($user, $pass) {
 if($this->model->isRegistered($user)
 {
  return false;
 }

 $this->twitter->login($user, $pass);
 if($this->twitter->isLoggedIn())
 {
  return $this-model->addUser($user, $pass);
 }

 return false;
}
```

Style 3

```
public function register($user, $pass) {
 if($this->model->isRegistered($user)
 {
  return false;
 }

 $status = $this->twitter->login($user, $pass);
 if($status)
 {
  return $this->model->addUser($user, $pass);
 }

 return false;
}
```

I'm currently making use of Style 1. Though I'm not quite sure if its the right one.

Comment: Are these really stylistic differences?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't know which style to choose. I'd say it would not make much difference.

Comment: The different styles should show varying degrees of readability. Though the differences aren't really obvious to me since I'm the one coding 'em. That's why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't want to sound too rude but I like noone of the 3 proposed styles. If I'm checking for conditions preventing the execution of a function, I'll always stick with this style. In general:

```
function action()
{
    if ($guard_condition1)
        return $failure;

    if ($guard_condition2)
        return $failure;

    do_action();
    return $success;
}
```

So I'd rewrite your code as following:

```
public function register($user, $pass)
{
    if ($this->model->isRegistered($user))
        return false;

    if (!$this->twitter->login($user, $pass))
        return false;

    return $this->model->addUser($user, $pass);
}
```

Anyway, if you need an opinion on what you proposed, I'd vote for style 3.

Answer (score 2):

In Style 1 "if" and "else if" is used on different conditions, so it doesn't make sense.

In Style 2 lines:

```
 $this->twitter->login($user, $pass);
 if($this->twitter->isLoggedIn())
```

are too much hard to read in some situations but it's a proper.

For me the best one is Style 3.

Comment: By definition `else if` always has a different condition than the preceding `if`, so your objection doesn't make sense :-)